# Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B \to A$ be monomorphisms. When is $A$ isomorphic to $B$?

Tags: category-theory

This is true for sets by the Schröder–Bernstein theorem where monomorphisms are injective functions. Is there a general type of category in which this condition holds? I suspect it holds [regular categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_category) or maybe [abelian categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category). (I will accept any reasonable answer more general than just the category of sets.)

This is not true in general; consider the category freely generated by $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to A$ in which $f$ and $g$ are both mono (somewhat vacuously) but are not isomorphic.

---

My attempt was to start with abelian categories since it is the strongest (and work backwards): assume $f$ and $g$ are both [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_morphism). Then they are the kernel of some $\alpha:A \to C$ and $\beta:B \to D$ with $f\beta:A \to D$ and $g\alpha:B\to C$ being zero morphisms (writing composition from left to right). So we can multiply on the left freely:

$$ f\beta = fgf\beta=fgfgf\beta=\cdots $$

$$ g\alpha = gfg\alpha =gfgfg\alpha=\cdots$$

By the universal property of the kernel we can choose $k=fgf$ so that $k\beta$ is a zero morphism and find unique $u:A \to A$ such that $uf=fgf$. Since $f$ is mono we have $u=fg$. (I was hoping $u$ would be the identity.)

Likewise we can take $k'=gfg$ so that $k'\alpha$ is a zero morphism and find $u':B \to B$ such that $u'g=gfg$, so that $u'=gf$. Again, not making much progress...

Comment: You should check this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold/202022#202022, especially the post by John Goodrick. A particular example that shows it fails for regular categories is the category of groups, where you have embeddings each way between the free group on two elements and the free group on three (for instance).

Comment: It might be interesting to note that it isn't true in general on a topos -- which is a category which acts very much like the category of sets, except that its "internal logic" does not satisfy the law of excluded middle in general.

Comment: You can also rule out abelian categories, because it already fails for abelian groups. Consider for example $\mathbb{Z}/(2) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(4) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(4) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(4) \oplus \ldots$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(4) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(4) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(4) \oplus \ldots$.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, every topos is a regular category...

Comment: @user43208 very nice resource, I'm tempted to call that an "answer" since it was discussed at length there.